# When can remove absolute value symbol in ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

There are two examples

> $$
> \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x}
> $$

and

> $$
> 2\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x}
> $$

The first one , we have
$$
\ln |y| = \ln |x| + C_1 \Rightarrow |y| = e^{C_1}|x| \Rightarrow  y = Cx.
$$
Its absolute value sign can be removed and use a constants $C$.

The second one, we have
$$
2\ln |y| = \ln |x| + C_1 \Rightarrow y^2 = e^{C_1}|x| \Rightarrow y^2 = C|x|.
$$
Its absolute value sign cant be removed.

I use the above way to judge whether the absolute value can be removed. For the first one

1. when $x > 0, y > 0$, we have
   $$
    \ln y = \ln x + C_1 \Rightarrow y = C_2 x.
    $$
2. when $x < 0, y > 0$, we have
   $$
    \ln y = \ln -x + C_1 \Rightarrow y = C_3 x.
    $$
3. when $x > 0 , y < 0$, we have
   $$
    \ln -y = \ln x + C_1 \Rightarrow y= C_4 x.
    $$
4. when $x < 0, y < 0$, we have
   $$
    \ln -y = \ln -x + C_1 \Rightarrow y = C_5 x.
    $$
5. when $y = 0$, we have
   $$
    y = 0 \Rightarrow y = 0 \cdot x.
    $$

Thus, finally the solution can be $y = Cx$.

For the second,

1. when $x > 0, y > 0$, we have
   $$
   y = C\sqrt{x}.
   $$
2. when $x < 0, y > 0$, we have
   $$
   y = C\sqrt{-x}.
   $$

Thus, its cant be removed absolute value.

My doubt is there exists cheap way to judge the absolute value can be removed? Thanks in advance!